# How do i manipulate a cylinder i have inserted

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

[image][image]Hi People :) ok Thanks to Bruno's advise i have been able to move forward a lot with this project Thank you however i have hit another snag and i have tried various things in edit mode to try and do this but ot no avail so i am hoping someone can help me on this to :) as you can see in the picture i have attached there is a picture of what i am trying to copy ( starbug 1 ) and my blender model now as you can see in the first picture the engines round off at the back however my cylinders are round and squared off to go long ways so my question is how do i manipulate this shape to bend down as shown in the original starbug picture?

Many thanks

Simon[image]

Answer (score 9):

## All hail Warp Tool

Keep the 3D cursor in the middle of the sphere and place a cylinder half inside the sphere. Scale both sides of the cylinder separately so they have the right diameter.

[image: truncated cone]

Then give the cylinder as many edge loops as you'd like with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>. Keep in mind that it will get stretched quite a bit in a moment.

[image: loopcut cone]

Now use the warp tool (Mesh>>Transform>>Warp or spacebar). The warp tool bends all selected verts around the 3D cursor. Use the redo panel to the left to set the angle to about 60 degrees, maybe 70.

The warp tool uses the 3D cursor as it's pivot point so make sure it's still in the sphere's center. It also uses the orientation of your window to define the axis. So it's important to normally use one of the main views, ideally without perspective. In this case I use Right Ortho.

[image: warped loopcut cone]

I recommend doing that on top of the sphere, finish the entire assembly (exhaust nozzle) and then rotate it from the front to 37 degrees or whatever is closest to the original.

[image: front view]

[image: rotated correctly]

After that you can either use a mirror modifier or mirror around the cursor by scaling -1 using the right axis.

[image: finished result]

Keep your objects along the axes as long as possible to make your work easier. Then place them after they're done.

Tip: Work with single meshes. Easier to select or manipulate, you can make safety copies and hide them with <kbd>H</kbd>. You can join them later with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>

Comment: Could i not do that with the cylinder already in place? please forgive me i am a complete beginner at this. also could i be a pian in the butt and ask you to post a step by step a GIF instruction as i am a complete beginner who do's not yet know myself around blender just yet :) would totaly apreciate it :) Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I am on 64kbit internet and manually creating a gif of that length is beyond my threshold. I have explained it properly, the rest is reading documentation. Throw your two cylinders away because the warp tool is view dependent. Big gifs take ages to load. It's always hard to learn Blender by picking a complex task without having videotuts or a teacher. Brute force method would be to download the documentation and simply read it once. I usually do it that way. Which part is unclear, what have you tried?

Comment: I'm using blender now for almost a decade, but I've never touched the warp tool. This looks incredibly useful, oh how I love this stack exchange.

Comment: Hi Haunted_house i have not tried just yet but will do :)

Comment: if there's any blind spots, I can try to add it in the answer.. Here's the docs for the warp tool: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/warp.html?highlight=warp

Comment: hi @yann the warp tool is older than my Blender history and I started with 2.12 so it's an old friend. Back then there was almost no undo, no redo and no numeric input though. It's extremely helpful to bend shapes in a controlled and uniform way. I downloaded the docs and will read them front to back, so my blind spots will get smaller too. Some of the newer stuff evaded my radar.

Comment: Heya Haunted thank you, i'm not totally there yet but i will be kinda having trouble with the transform and warp tool when i type the seetings show in your display it dont come out as tidy and neat yours i will doa screen shot and post :) i'l get there. I have found a more manual way of doing it when i insert the edge loops if i slect all the points at the edge then drag it across and down then straighten out the other points that look off once stretched i can do it that way however it is more manual :) i want to learn as many ways for the same thing as possible as ia m starting out :)

Comment: Ok how do you get to the 2D flat view in bklender that you have in the first picture so i can place my items on the right axis :)

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/align.html https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/projections.html

Answer (score 1):

Select the cylinder with RMB, hit R, then Y for rotation around Y axis (or likewise X or Z), move your mouse until you have the angle you want click LMB or RMB to cancel the rotation. Hold CTRL key while rotating to rotate in 5 degree increments.

Also you might want to check [Blender Documentation](https://www.blender.org/support/tutorials/) to learn the basics more efficiently.

Comment: Hi I think you missunderstood what i wanted or maybe i did not write it properly, i hit R but it just rotated it did not stretch and curve round like in the picture the first one, the engine cyclinders i need to select and stretch and curve it out over the sphere so it connects with other one, can you see what i mean? :)

Answer (score 1):

Proportional Editing is your friend here though I am sure curve extrusion should also work.

Use mousewheel to change the size of the proportional editing effect volume/area. Also, try different falloff (linear/bell curve etc..) which influences neighbors differently.

[image: cynlinder deform using propoertional editing]

Comment: I tried PET too, but it distorted the edgerings. It's better if they all point to the center.

Comment: Heya bruno ok i am a complete beginner some of the terminology is a bit overwelming :)

Comment: I shall give it a go with the GIF instruction infront of me on my other computer when i get home and get back to you, but how do i get them dot's into the cylinder? i must sound like a complete idiot to you :) and are them dot's what bend the shape of the object?

Comment: Oh i get i think, tell me if i am correct, depending on how much you want to manipulate the object you put as much loop cut rings in there if you want to distort it a lot if not then put as few as possible?

Comment: Heya bruno please take a look at the picture above have i dont it correctly?  the loop cuts i mean. The last bit i am having trouble with it dont bend the right way i need it to again probably me missing something out.

Comment: Use transform/warp as suggested by @Haunt_House. It is a cleaner solution

Comment: What on the cylinder?