# How to keep the circular part of the cone a circle whilst bending the rest?

Tags: transforms

Ok as much as I have got the hang of it now there is one snagging issue when I warp the cone it don't keep the original straight edge all around at the back, it warps that to

[image]

How do I keep the back circle part of the cone straight and round all the way round but bend the rest of the shape

Comment: Ok bit of an update what i did was possition the warped shape were i wanted it elongated it to go past by a fair bit were i wanted it to then i created boolean created a cube and chopped off the excess, if that is going to cause problems later polease do advise also if you could still provide the answer as i feel i have just used a short cut rather than learnt something. Many thanks :), Si.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is, the warp tool only works on selected vertices, so you could in theory leave the back ring of vertices of your cone unselected.  However, assuming you're using the method by @Haunt_House in [this answer,](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100223/how-do-i-manipulate-a-cylinder-i-have-inserted) I am not sure you will find the results satisfactory, because there will be a strangely shaped discontinuity between the warped and unwarped vertices.

Instead I think you might be better served by cleanly chopping off the back portion of your transformed cylinder.  There are a couple of ways you could do this.  You could create a cube and use the Boolean modifier in "Difference" mode:

[image: without boolean modifier]

[image: with boolean modifier]

Or, in edit mode, you could create a plane and scale and orient it for correct chopping:

[image: cone and plane]

Then position the plane where you want to make the cut:

[image: cone and plane positioned]

Then select all vertices and choose Mesh-->Faces-->Intersect (Knife) and make sure the source is set to "Self Intersect" and the separate mode is set to "Cut".  This will result in a divided geometry in which you can move or delete unneeded sections (I have deleted the plane in the screenshots below because it is no longer needed):

[image: cone and plane after cut]

[image: cone and plane after cut 2]

[image: cone and plane after cut 3]

Comment: Heya rising fall thanks for that very usefull :) all solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Warp the cone around the cursor in front view. For example 60°

[image]

Then, again around the cursor, rotate the cone back 30°. Half of what you warped it.

[image]

That's the way I did it on the starbug example. Clean topology.